# Preview SQL when DbEntityValidationException occurs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, orm, profiling

Sometime when I try to put data into database I get DbEntityValidationException. There is EntityValidationError property which contain error info. Everything is great, but how can I preview SQL command, which try insert data.

I use EF6 and MS SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

In your `DbContext` there is a `Database` property. On this there is a `Action<string>` property called Log. You could assign a delegate and have the log write to a console window.

```
context.Database.Log = msg => Console.WriteLine(msg);
```

Comment: Maybe you needed to be more clear with your answer. Just guessing, I did not down vote by the way

Comment: @Krishna would you happen to think the answer is worthy of an up vote? :-)